OpenLayers, WKT geometry incorrect depending on data projection
I'm trying to show some geometries, similar to the example on https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wkt.html
This works fine with WGS84:
const wkt = 'POLYGON ((15.7007999816072 60.3526465816716, 16.1364878678286 60.3526465816716, 16.1364878678286 60.6103107068803, 15.7007999816072 60.6103107068803, 15.7007999816072 60.3526465816716))';

...
format.readFeature(wkt, {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',    //WGS84
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857', //OpenLayers Mercator
}),

But if I use the same geometry in Sweref99 TM like this:
const wkt = 'POLYGON ((538595.477 6690969.085, 562217.352 6690969.085, 562217.352 6719920.922, 538595.477 6719920.922, 538595.477 6690969.085))';

...
format.readFeature(wkt, {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:3006',    //Sweref99 TM
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857', //OpenLayers Mercator
}),

Then it shows up in the Netherlands instead of in Sweden!
Am I missing something here or is there a bug with this coordinate system?
Update:
No, I did not know about proj4. So it seems I need to call
proj4.defs(...)
proj4.register(...)

Included in OpenLayers is a proj4.js that I tried to import. It has a register method but no defs method. (Although there are comments in the file about calling proj4.defs.) So I'm a little confused what I need to do.
Update2:
Ok, I figured out that "proj4" included in OpenLayers is just code for using "proj4" and I need to add that to my project. So I think it should be something like:
import * as olProj4 from 'ol/proj/proj4';
import proj4 from 'proj4';
...
proj4.defs("EPSG:3006", "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs");
olProj4.register(proj4);

But now I have a problem importing proj4 in TypeScript.
import proj4 from 'proj4';

results in Module "xxxx/npm/node_modules/@types/proj4/index" can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag
import * as proj4 from 'proj4';

results in "defs" is not exported by "node_modules/proj4/lib/index.js", imported by "xxx.ts"
Update 3: I added the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' and 'esModuleInterop' flags and it seems to work now and the geometries are positioned correctly.

Have you defined the projection in proj4 then registered proj4?
